# Excel VBA Loop through column to find specific text and copy /paste from different column in same row to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Using office 365, I am trying to build this in stages as I have never taken on a project like this.  We have a work group that manages overall tasks in one main workbook that is updated weekly.  Each task has functions that are filtered down to smaller groups to perform.  They want to be able to copy and paste specific cell values to a separate workbook for each of the small groups using VBA to automate this task.  The wrench in the works, is that many of the cells that need to be copied are merged cells.  Initially, I wrote this to capture the columns I wanted to copy from and did it in the same workbook:

```
    Dim NextRow As Range

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Copy
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Set NextRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    NextRow.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial (xlValues), Transpose:=False
```

Then, since I want to loop through and find specific text in column D and only copy from specific cells in the row of the active cell, I updated to this:

```
    Dim NextRow As Range
    Dim rnge As Range
    Dim iRow As Long

    iRow = ActiveCell.Row
 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Set NextRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    NextRow.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial (xlValues), Transpose:=False
```

Next I added the loop and that is where things went wrong.  I am not getting any errors, but I am not getting the correct information copied over so I have missed something in how I approached my loop.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Dim NextRow As Range
    Dim rnge As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    iRow = ActiveCell.Row

    Set rnge = Range("E2:E25")
    For Each cell In rnge
        If cell.Value = "GRP1" Then
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Set NextRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    NextRow.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial (xlValues), Transpose:=False
    
    End If
        Next cell
```

Comment: Please accept a friendly advice: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Despite the header, it is not only about `Select` but also about many other keywords that should be avoided. Another advice: learn to single step through the code and follow how variable values change.

Answer (score 2):

### A VBA Lookup

```vb
Sub VbaLookup()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Range("E2:E25")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    
    Dim scell As Range
    
    For Each scell In slrg.Cells
        If scell.Value = "GRP1" Then
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1)
            dcell.Value = sws.Cells(scell.Row, "B").Value
            ' or e.g.:
            'dcell.Value = scell.EntireRow.Columns("B").Value
        End If
    Next scell

End Sub
```